# How to connect Many-to-one relations in FaunaDB

Tags: graphql, faunadb

I’ve got the following GraphQL schema uploaded to my FaunaDB:

```scheme
type RSheet @collection(name: "sheets") {
  columns: [RColumn!]! @relation
  sections: [RSection]!
}

type RColumn @collection(name: "columns") {
  label: String!
  sheet: RSheet!
}

type RSection @embedded {
  label: String
  items: [[RItem!]]!
}

type RItem @embedded {
  value: String
  form: RItemForm
  column: RColumn!
}

enum RItemForm {
  STRING
}
```

That is a sheet with columns and a number of sections with items that make the rows of a table.

---

Now, I’ve created a sheet as well as two columns.

**“sheets”** collection in the database

```json
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("sheets"), "304268724760740364"),
  "sections": [
    {
      "label": null,
      "items": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**“columns”** collection in the database

```json
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("columns"), "304268724764934668"),
  "label": "Begin",
  "sheet": Ref(Collection("sheets"), "304268724760740364")
},
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("columns"), "304268724776469004"),
  "label": "End",
  "sheet": Ref(Collection("sheets"), "304268724760740364")
}
```

All this works fine so far. I can create sheets and/or columns, update, and delete them.

---

However, if I want to add a section item using FaunaDB’s GraphQL I can’t [connect](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/graphql/relations#connect) the item’s columns. I get an error stating that I have to provide the column’s `ID!`:

[image: Screenshot of the GraphQL error]

When I do so, only the ID is written to the database and a connection `Ref(…)` is not created:

**“sheets”** collection in the database

```json
{
    "ref": Ref(Collection("sheets"), "304268724760740364"),
    "sections": [
      label: null
      {
        "items": [
          [
            {
              "value": "Item 1",
              "column": "304268724791149068"  /// EXPECTED: Ref(Collection("columns"), "304268724791149068")
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create relations inside embedded types.  From the [docs on relations](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/graphql/relations):

> The relationship recognition algorithm looks at every field for all non-embedded types

I do think it would be nice to have relationships work through `@embedded` types, but that is not what they were really intended for, so it is not supported.

You will need to rework your schema so that each connection is in an non-embedded type. Also, the 2-dimensional array is also not possible with connections.

### Example

Consider the following schema

```
type RSheet @collection(name: "sheets") {
  columns: [RColumn!]! @relation
  sections: [RSection]! @relation
}

type RColumn @collection(name: "columns") {
  label: String!
  sheet: RSheet! @relation
  items: [RItem!] @relation
}

type RSection @collection(name: "section") {
  label: String
  sheet: RSheet @relation
  items: [RSectionItemList!]! @relation
}

type RSectionItemList @collection(name: "section_item_list") {
  section: RSection! @relation
  items: [RItem!]! @relation
}

type RItem @collection(name: "item") {
  value: String
  form: RItemForm
  column: RColumn! @relation
  list: RSectionItemList @relation
}

enum RItemForm {
  STRING
}
```

Note how I split the 2-dimensional array into a list of wrapper list objects.

A sheet and columns could be created like this:

[image]

And items added like this:

[image]

Comment: Aww, I must have overlooked the information about embedded types. Thank you very much for your answer and for the effort you put into it! This helps a lot.